# Linux folder identification or metadata in php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, metadata, directory

I've developed a kind of internal business webdrive.
The data contains 'root folders' all users can be set to have read or read/write permissions on these folders. 
This data is stores in a MySQL db.
How can I identify the folders? At the moment, they are listed by the foldername in the db. But whenever the folder is renamed, the link is lost.

Is there another way to identify a folder? Some kind of un changeable uid? Metadata? Unaffected by folder rename or move and accessible by php?

Comment: Why don't you do all renaming through the application? Then it can update the db at the same time?

Comment: Because admin can access the system via AFP and ftp

Comment: tell admin not to do that, since it breaks the application. Or he should update the DB when he does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding attributes with "xattr".

Or you could use the inode number - that is exactly what you asked for - an unchangeable unique number associated with a folder. It will only ever change if you copy the folder to a different  filesystem - but maybe you aren't doing that.

```
mkdir aaa
ls -ldi aaa
2847311 drwxr-xr-x  2 mark  staff  68  3 Dec 09:48 aaa
mv aaa bbb
ls -ldi bbb
2847311 drwxr-xr-x  2 mark  staff  68  3 Dec 09:48 bbb
```

Comment: However, finding a folder by inode number is not efficient.

Comment: That is true, Barmar. Hopefully, the users will learn not to rename their stuff too often ;-)  Or maybe the area within which they can rename is relatively constrained by permissions, or capacity or filesystem so it won't be too bad.

Comment: Or maybe the OP doesn't need to find the folder, but just check if he is in it. Or maybe the check can be done offline at night or somesuch. Just looking for solutions really, rather than obstacles ;-)

Comment: tried xattr but having trouble installing the pecl module.. says libattr isn't installed although it is.. php function fileinode() however works out of the box and as you said, I only have to check if the inode of the working folder is in DB, so I don't have to look for the folder by inode. One way only. So this is the correct answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use incron as a trigger:

```
http://www.howtoforge.com/triggering-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron
```

Call a shell script to make the database changes when a file is renamed.